# How to set different background color for settings window, other than Editor Background

Tags: visual-studio-code, background, themes

As the title suggests, I have specific color overrides in my settings.json.

There is `editor.background`, but I was wondering for those windows for when code isn't open? Like the settings window, etc.

Comment: well, I think it should still be closed as a duplicate since it's the same issue. [the point of duplicate closure](/help/duplicates) is so that the answers can be found in one place. keeping this question post open would subvert that.

Comment: you should have a box asking if it is a duplicate above your question. if not, use the flag button under your post beside the "follow" button.